# How to get JSON value using TJSONObject class in C++ Builder?

Tags: json, c++builder

I couldn't get certain JSON Value using `TJSONObject`, i get error of `Access violation at address xxxxxxxxx`.

I have a problem getting the desired value using it's key name from JSON File,
i'm currently using `TRESTClient`, `TRESTRequest`, `TRESTResponse` to get JSON data from the web, i used same JSON URL with Javascript and works fine, but in C++ Builder it doesn't, it simply showing me an error of `Access violation at address xxxxxxxxx blablabla`, that happens when i try get certain JSON value using it's name like for EX: `"name": "sparky"`, but when i get full JSON File it succeeds without errors.

**Code:**

```
TJSONObject *JSONObject = new TJSONObject();

__try
{
    RESTClient1->BaseURL = "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json";
    RESTRequest1->Execute();
    JSONObject = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>( TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(RESTResponse1->JSONText) ) ;
    TJSONPair *pair = JSONObject->Get("name");
    Memo1->Text = pair->JsonValue->ToString();

}
__finally
{
    delete JSONObject;
}
```

**UPDATE:** This is The JSON file which i want to get the values from.

```
[
    {
    "name":"Meowsy",
    "species":"cat",
    "foods":
    {
      "likes":
      [
        "tuna",
        "catnip"
      ]
,
      "dislikes":
      [
        "ham",
        "zucchini"
      ]
    }
  }
,

  {
    "name":"Barky",
    "species":"dog",
    "foods":
    {
      "likes":
      [
        "bones",
        "carrots"
      ]
,
      "dislikes":
      [
        "tuna"
      ]
    }
  }
,

  {
    "name":"Purrpaws",
    "species":"cat",
    "foods":
    {
      "likes":
      [
        "mice"
      ]
,
      "dislikes":
      [
        "cookies"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: ParseJSONValue returns a NULL object if parsing fails. You don't check if JSONObject is valid (not NULL) before you use it. **Debug your code** and check what RESTResponse->JSONText contains and if JSONObject is NULL:

Comment: FWIW, you create a memory leak. You create JSONObject but overwrite its reference with the result of ParseJSONValue. This means that the original value is not refeenced anymore, is therefore unreachable and cannot be deleted anymore. So you have a leak.

Comment: JSONObject is valid, i already checked that, and it returns json string in `TMemo`,
but the problem is it doesn't give me a certain value like i explained in my question,
btw, i took the above code from https://qiita.com/7of9/items/522ebfd25328df5c7777

Comment: So, what's the solution

Comment: So I assume the pair is not valid? What is the text in the JSONObject? If it is not too big, post that too. And take care of the memory leak.

Comment: FWIW "JSONObject is valid, i already checked that". Would be nice if you had stated that in the question. Please give all relevant information, so people don't have to speculate or ask.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE** above

Comment: I'll take a look when I have the time, later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON you have shown is an ARRAY OF OBJECTS rather than a SINGLE OBJECT, like your code assumes it is.  So `TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue()` would return a [`TJSONArray`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONArray) instead of a [`TJSONObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject), and as such there is no way that your assertion in comments that the "JSONObject is valid" can be true since `dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>` would fail and return NULL, which your code is not checking for.  You did not show the FULL error message, but if it says "read of address 00000000", that is a good indication that a NULL pointer is being accessed.

Also, [`TJSONObject::Get()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.Get) is deprecated. To retrieve a value by name, use [`TJSONObject::GetValue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.GetValue) instead.

Also, `TRESTResponse` can parse the JSON for you, if you use the [`TRESTResponse::JSONValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTResponse.JSONValue) property instead of the [`TRESTResponse::JSONText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTResponse.JSONText) property.

Also, you are leaking the `TJSONObject` that you allocate, if your code is compiled using one of the non-ARC-based C++ compilers.

With that said, try this:

```
RESTClient1->BaseURL = "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json";
RESTRequest1->Execute();

Memo1->Clear();

TJSONValue *JSONValue = RESTResponse1->JSONValue;
if (JSONValue)
{
    if (TJSONArray *JSONArray = dynamic_cast<TJSONArray*>(JSONValue))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < JSONArray->Count; ++i)
        {
            TJSONObject *JSONObject = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>(JSONArray->Items[i]);
            if (JSONObject)
            {
                TJSONValue *JSONObjectName = JSONObject->GetValue("name");
                if (JSONObjectName)
                    Memo1->Lines->Add(JSONObjectName->Value());
            }
        }
    }
    else if (TJSONObject JSONObject = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>(JSONValue))
    {
        TJSONValue *JSONObjectName = JSONObject->GetValue("name");
        if (JSONObjectName)
            Memo1->Text = JSONObjectName->Value();
    }
    else
    {
        Memo1->Text = "Ignoring unsupported JSON value type";
    }
}
else
{
    Memo1->Text = "JSON not parsed";
}
```

Comment: I know i'm still noob at C++ programming, a lot of times those small things get me confused in my level of programming, but i'm learning new things on the way, and thank you so much for your help.

Comment: "Also, the code you showed should not even compile, because TJSONObject::Get() takes an numeric index as input, not a key name". There is an overload that takes a name, but it is deprecated. It should compile, though.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis apparently both overloads of `TJSONObject::Get()` are deprecated. But point taken about the code compiling. I updated my answer